# How can I make a function in which password is changing when a user is not logged in?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, change-password

```
onChangePasswordPress = () => {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    user.updatePassword(this.state.newPassword).then(function(){
      console.log('Password is changed');
    }).catch(function(error){
      console.log(error.message)
    })
```

it says currentUser in the 2nd line means only a user who is logged in can change his/her password.So how can we change a password of a user when a user is not logged in his/her account . How to make a function of changing a password when a user is not logged in his/her account in react native

Answer (score 0):

For a user to be able to [update their password](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#set_a_users_password), they need to have recently signed in. This is a security requirement, as allowing changing a password without being signed in would be a huge security risk.

If the user forgot their password, you can [send them a password reset email](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#set_a_users_password). This email contains a link they then click that allows them to set a new password.

If you want to allow an application admin to change a user's password, you can build that [using the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user). But to prevent the security risk outlined before, this can only be done from a trusted environment, such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions.

Comment: I've tried that sending a password reset email but that also requires a user to signed in recently otherwise it won't send email if we can make a function that the user is not logged in but in order to send the email first you have to put your email first that the email will be sent

Comment: Sending a password reset email should **not** require a recent sign-in, as that would defeat its purpose. Can you show how you tested that, and what exact error message you got with what code?